# woocommerce unable to make generic function for function.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to modify login message and class on woocommerce checkout page

I have modified the core files but I want to do it via Functions.php so that i can put the code snippet in functions.php

Current Code

```
<?php wc_print_notice( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_login_message', __( 'Returning customer?', 'woocommerce' ) ) . ' <a href="#" class="showlogin">' . __( 'Click here to login', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>', 'notice' ); ?>
```

What i want - I am changing frontend messages and class

```
<?php wc_print_notice( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_login_message', __( 'Dear customer?', 'woocommerce' ) ) . ' <a href="#" class="digits-login-modal">' . __( 'Click here to login or register', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>', 'notice' ); ?>
```

No errors

Answer (score 1):

WooCommerce has a lot of customizability built into the plugin, which is really nice. When you want to change a message or something built into the plugin, you can usually do so with template files. In your active theme, you want to add a folder called "woocommerce", and then add the files you want to override there.

Here are the documents for overriding the template https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

You could also probably do something like this in the theme's functions.php file if you don't want to override template files

```
    // define the woocommerce_checkout_login_message callback 
    function filter_woocommerce_checkout_login_message( $var ) { 
        // make filter magic happen here... 
        return $var; 
    }; 

    // add the filter 
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_login_message', 'filter_woocommerce_checkout_login_message', 10, 1 );
```

Source for above code:
http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_checkout_login_message/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I am a beginner and I will definitely try the template model however, is it possible that I can get the exact code which I can put it in functions.php. I am actually changing the class too not sure how this will be accommodated in the above mentioned code by you. Sorry if I am asking the basics in the learning phase :)